# Forms floated labels

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/95dew2mj/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="input-box">
    <label for="option_159" class="required">
        Patient Name                                        <em>*</em>      
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="optionli-input input-text product-custom-option required-entry"  placeholder="Patient Name" >
</div>
```

I want to create something like this

[example](https://www.screencast.com/t/38VVshqGW)

How can I create such an example only from CSS?

Can you modify my example so I can get something like this please? I want to understand how it was created.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```html
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Name:</legend>
   <input type="text"><br>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using fieldset-legend

```html
<div class="input-box">
<fieldset>
    <legend for="option_159" class="required">Patient Name <em>*</em></legend>
    <input type="text" class="optionli-input input-text product-custom-option required-entry"  placeholder="Patient Name" >
  </fieldset> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```css
 label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
 }
 input{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="input-box">
 <label for="option_159" class="required">Patient Name<em>*</em></label>
 <br/>
 <input type="text" class="optionli-input input-text product-custom-option required-entry"  placeholder="Patient Name" / >
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use This :**

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
}

div input[type] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 300px;
}

div label {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    color: skyblue;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="option_159">Patient Name<em>*</em></label>
    <input type="text"  id="option_159" placeholder="Patient Name">
</div>
```